# math to use to average out distorted values

Tags: c#, math

I got some values that are randomly distorted, and now i am looking for a way to to average out the distortion.

in the code below i have an example of my problem, an array a of measurements a[]. And i got a random array distortion[]. This created by rnd.Nextbytes

with array b[] i try to get close to the values of array a[]

In the samplecode i am using 10.000 samples, but it is not realy fixed, 100.000 samples would be ok too, in the end i'd rather let it run for a time period or till a key is pressed.

```
using System;
namespace test_math
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        byte[] distortion = new byte[8];

        int[] b = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        int[] a = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800 };

        for (int count = 0; count < 100000; count++)
        {
            Console.Write(count+ "  ");
            rnd.NextBytes(distortion);              
            for (int i = 0; i < distortion.Length; i++)
            {
                b[i] = (int)(b[i] * .8 + (a[i] + 127-(int)(distortion[i])) * .2);
                Console.Write(b[i].ToString() + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
 }
```

Currently it with the line

```
  b[i] = (int)(b[i] * .8 + (a[i] + 127-(int)(distortion[i])) * .2);
```

Where .8 and .2 are factors (and i tested with other numbers as well).
But i do think that this is far from ideal, while although such math has a dampening effect it doesnt take into account that at some point in time the new measurements should have less effect on the average of b[]

PS i dont now how to call this nearing to a value in statistical terms, if there is a term for it, i be happy to know it it too.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.  Specifically, it is unclear what part of the above is given, what is the required result, and what part of the above represents your unsuccessful attempt to get from what is given to the required result.

Comment: Over time, it seems clear that assuming a good random distribution, the values should converge on the correct value. But it's not clear what your goal is, in terms of improving on what you have. What exactly is the code doing now, and how _specifically_ is that different from what you want it to do?

Comment: in the code above b[] doesnt converge to a[]
Essentially a[n] is distorted by a[n]+random(-127..+127) 
I'm looking for math that when repeated enough times with a[n]+random; would converge b[] to the original values of a[] . So b[] aprouches {100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800}.
The code is just an easy to copy and editable example of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not entirely clear on what your goal is here. However, mathematically, I would expect that the idea should be to average the samples over time. Taking that literally, that just means you would simply add them together with each iteration, and then to find the converged value, divide by the total number of samples.

This version of your code does that (I took a bit of liberty with your output logic, so that the code would complete in a reasonable time and not fill up the console window buffer):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    byte[] distortion = new byte[8];

    long[] b = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int[] a = { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800 };

    for (int count = 1; count <= 100000; count++)
    {
        bool display = count % 100 == 0;

        if (display)
        {
            Console.Write(count + "  ");
        }
        rnd.NextBytes(distortion);
        for (int i = 0; i < distortion.Length; i++)
        {
            int distortedValue = a[i] + 127 - (int)(distortion[i]);

            b[i] += distortedValue;

            if (display)
            {
                Console.Write(((int)((double)b[i] / count + 0.5)).ToString() + " ");
            }
        }

        if (display)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Given enough samples, this eventually converges on the original values. If you really want to use a variation on a weighted sum, I suppose you could. That would involve reconstructing the previous sum by multiplying the `b[]` array value by `count - 1`, adding the current distorted value, and then dividing that by `count` again before storing it back into the `b[]` array.

Comment: Seams to work quite well, has it a name in statistics ?.
And would there be a behaviour difference with the other option you suggest in the comment.

Comment: This Averaging seams to work quite well, Would there be a behaviour difference with the other option you suggest in the comment (would it converge faster?).  Not sure yet if slower or faster converging is better in my situation

Comment: @user3800527: _"has it a name in statistics"_ -- don't know. I'm not a statistician. :) _"would there be a behaviour difference"_ -- no difference. Mathematically, the two approaches are identical. It's just that in one case, you only compute the average when you want to display the current progress, while in the other you are effectively recomputing the average with each iteration. In either case, convergence happens very quickly; after 100 iterations, you're within about 10%, and 1000 iterations, closer to 1%.

Comment: Do note that if you choose the running average approach, you'll need to store that running average as `double`, otherwise the rounding error interferes with the convergence.

Comment: I just heard from a friend that in engineering they call it PID control.
in statistics i think it might be just average ?..
it might even be possible to get faster to the average, but i find it fast enough.